# Drive Migrator Fail Message

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I got the following message to my email:

> Your script, Drive Migrator, has recently failed to finish
>   successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure
>   the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving
>   future failure notifications, click here.  Details: 
>   Start Function    Error Message   Trigger End 4/22/15 1:56
>   PM    processFilesAndFolders  Exceeded maximum execution
>   time  time-based  4/22/15 2:02 PM Sincerely,  Google Apps Script  Need
>   help? Visit the Google Apps Script documentation. Please do not reply
>   to this message. (c) 2015 Google

I'm confused though because I got an email several hours prior to that saying "Google Drive Copy-Success" (I used the Drive Migrator to make a backup copy of a folder in my drive)-- it appears to have copied successfully but then I got the error message so I'm not sure if I need to back it up again because it didn't finalize something or what...

Please let me know whether the backup was a success or if it failed per the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the particular script you ran, thus impossible to answer if it did the full copy. What likely happened is that the script handles that error by continuing the copy (using time triggers). When one of those triggers runs out of time, google will send the error (likely because you requested those errors when the trigger was added). Google has an option to send the error later instead of inmediately (for example to receive a summary of errors at the end of the day). Thus even if the script finished ok that error notification still is sent.