# Your script, Drive Migrator, has recently failed to finish successfully

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this email from google.

Your script, Drive Migrator, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

There are about 200 messages of the format:

```
Start   1/1/19 4:53 PM  
Function    processFilesAndFolders  
Error Message   Authorization is required to perform that action.   
Trigger     time-based  
End 1/1/19 4:53 PM
```

When i click there i fund there is an empty trigger and no further information.

```
Project - 
Last run - 
Deployment -
Event Time-based
Function - 
Error rate -
```

Its very strange given nobody was on the system at this time, and I cannot see any details about the trigger.

How do I see what is happening here? Is someone on my system, trying to move my files around? How is is possible to have a trigger that is void of information like this? It looks somewhat hacky. Can I centrally disable this "drive migrator"?

I found an old question about this: [Drive Migrator Fail Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811597/drive-migrator-fail-message)
But, perhaps it does not have enough information to get a proper answer.

I also contacted google support directly, but they said that asking here is the only way to get technical support on this service. I understand this is not the best "stackoverflow type question", but I'm at a loss on where to get further information about this.

Comment: If you go to view executions from the view menu in the script editor you will be able to see the failed executions.  Click on the down arrow on the right  and there's probably a description of the failure along with a line number and project filename.

Answer (score 0):

The failure notifications likely occur when a Google Script is deleted from your Drive without de-authorization or when the permissions get revoked for some reason.

Go [here](https://script.google.com/home/triggers) and you'll find a list of all triggers running under your Google account. Delete the one associated with your Failure emails.

This [guide](https://ctrlq.org/docs/20474-summary-failures-google-apps-script) explains how you can unsubscribe from the failure emails and also properly de-authorize the associated script.